# Why does the output of Show[ParametricPlot3d_1[],ParametricPlot3d_2[]...ParametricPlot3d_n[]] change?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Why don't the two images look identical? More importantly, how can I prevent this behavior?

[image]

Note: Plotrange=>All returns the same second image

Comment: Please, do not post images of your code, copy-paste it into the edit window of your question by using the icon “{}”...

Comment: Meanwhile, have you read about `HyperPlane` in the documentation?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, sorry hyperplane is totally unsuitable for my application. I will correct code shortly